# Track changes to InventoryCD for Stock Items

Tags: acumatica

I'm creating a contract API solution to keep items in sync between multiple tenants. Is there any way to track the changes to InventoryCD? In this case one Franchiser would like to update items in their 6 franchisees. It's easy for me to find the records that changed, but harder to know when the CD has changed (importantly what it chagned *FROM*). Certainly I could write customization to do it, but I thought maybe Acumatica has some option inbuilt.

Ideally I'd like to have a log of the changes with old and new CD. It's hosted so I don't think I can make it happen with DB Triggers (which is how pre-Acumatica me would have handled id)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Acumatica version. But have you tried looking at Business Events? I believe there is the ability to access the old and previous values.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at Acumatica's Audit history capabilities but be careful to only turn on the fields you need to track as the DB can grow very large if you turn on all fields on the Stock Item screen or for any screen.